# Prestashop says there's a payment error but it has worked

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm from Denmark and using a payment gateway called ePay. Up until now I've only accepted danish krone and now I want to use euros in addition. And here's the problem:

I CAN accept euros and the payment goes through as it should, but Prestashop says that there was an error with the payment and the customer also gets an email stating this.

Am I missing something in the settings? I'm using Prestashop Cloud so I'm not allowed to do a whole lot of file editing.

/Carl

Comment: I don't know ePay, maybe in it configuration you have to turn on €, like in paypal account. Also choosing cloud it was not good option, yes you have free hosting and 10 ticket, but for all problems no from their side you have to pay. It is better way move your shop to externall hosting.

Comment: you should report this issue to the developer of the module, they will help you better ....